# Table structure and validation

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2010

I have a table employee and wanted suggestion for defining the primary key/table. Initially I wanted to keep `EMP ID` field as primary key but then I also want to keep track of all changes- `TL Name` for an employee. This table should allow only one unique active `EMP ID`, however can allow multiple inactive `EMP ID`. Please suggest.

Below is sample structure of table.

```
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| ID | EMP ID | EMP Name | TL Name | Is Active |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | Z001   | Raj      | Vik     | No        |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 2  | Z002   | Ajay     | Peter   | No        |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 3  | Z001   | Raj      | Ashish  | No        |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 4  | Z003   | Soni     | Suresh  | Yes       |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 5  | Z001   | Raj      | Vinod   | Yes       |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Make Id primary and create another table with the changes with this id as foreign key and add a change_date column on this new table. It is a bad design to have history of a data in the same table.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Any reference link which guides how to manage the parent and changes table? Thank you!

Comment: Here is one: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/21068/audit-trail-generator-for-microsoft-sql

Comment: Is it Sql server or ms-access? very different products...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Its for MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) If you hv IsActive rule in table then EmpID can't be primary key.you hv to make it via code.

ii) If you remove IsAcTive rule,then I think EmpID is generated via code then in same code you can put one filter.so no point in making it as primary key.

Better make it CI.
iii) Make ID as PK.

iv) Many of them follow same desing pattern.If that table will grow into million of records and is very frequently use in search and join then this is definetly bad design.

If this is the case then keep seperate change table and removoe thos audit columns.

v) Even if your table is small then it is bad design.you hv to pay the price of writing isAtive='YES' in all the query.

vi) Though keeping seperate table require little more code and maintenance,it is worth doing.